# Can you use ExternalInterface.available to check if JavaScript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, installation, integration

Flash has the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class which can communicate to JavaScript running in the browser

Can you use the ExternalInterface.available property to check if JavaScript is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExternalInterface.available` just returned `true` while javascript was disabled in my firefox

Answer (score 5):

ExternalInterface.available will detect if the swf is in a housing document that is capable of providing an external scripting environment - like an HTML document.

if you want to test if javascript is actually "on", you can use a simple function with ExternalInterface.call that returns true.  something like this:

```
function JSAvailable():Boolean {

    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        if (ExternalInterface.call("Function(\"return true;\")")) {
            return true;
        }
    }           

    return false;

}
```